# C# console application caesar cipher displaying incorrect output

Tags: c#, console-application, caesar-cipher

I'm in the process of making a caesar cipher encryptor/decryptor for an assignment.   I am attempting to decrypt the contents of a .TXT file. The application is reading the contents of the .TXT file perfectly, however, when it comes to displaying the decrypted file it only shows 6 characters per shift.  I wish to display every possible outcome for each shift for ALL the contents of the .TXT file (please see picture for example of the issue.   Thanks in advanced for any help.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dgz4.png

```
    static void decryption()
    {   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
        Console.WriteLine ("\n*********************************** Decryption *********************************");
        Console.ResetColor();
        //pulls getPath from varables class
        string path = globalVars.getPath();


    string encrypted_text = path;     //String variable that contains [enter image description here][1]the text from a file. To get the text, the method in a class SystemIO is ran to read the text. It expects a parameter, which is a file directory.
    string decoded_text = " ";
    int shift = 0;
    char character = '0';
    encrypted_text = encrypted_text.ToUpper();

    char[] alphabet = new char[26] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',     'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

    Console.WriteLine("The encrypted text is \n{0}", encrypted_text);       //Display the encrypted text

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)        //Start a loop which will display 25 different candidates of decipher
    {
        decoded_text = "";
        foreach (char c in encrypted_text)
        {
            character = c;

            if (character == '\'' || character == ' ')
                continue;

            shift = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, character) - i;         //Define a shift which is the index of a character in an alphabet array, take away the itteration of this loop. Store the result in a variable
            if (shift <= 0)
                shift = shift + 26;

            if (shift >= 26)
                shift = shift - 26;


            decoded_text += alphabet[shift];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nShift {0} \n {1}", i + 1, decoded_text);
    }
}
```

Comment: "please see picture" what picture?

Comment: oh, I added it to the bottom of my code....

Comment: I copied your exact code into .net fiddle and it seems to work fine https://dotnetfiddle.net/ymICBt Is the text in your file 6 characters long?

Comment: I've just tested with an alternative .txt file @ColmPrunty and it seemed to work fine, exactly as you demoed...   But i'm still unable to display the specific .TXT file I need it to read...   Any ideas on what the issue could be?  thanks

Comment: do you think it could it be an issue with spaces or punctuation marks? @ColmPrunty

Comment: Must be something in the text file. Have you anything that could be an escape character when you read it in. You're checking for \ in the loop but it might filter things out before it gets there.

Comment: Ok, so I've created a next .txt file with the same content... Now it displays the first 26 characters from the .txt file, with the correct shift...... How do I display the entire contents of the .txt file?  @ColmPrunty    thanks :)

Comment: I can only guess you're using File.ReadLines, if you use File.ReadAllLines, it will give you back a string array. You'll need to call your decoding on each element of the array. Probably worth breaking the different parts into methods to make it readable.

Comment: Ok, thanks i'll do that....

Comment: this is my read file code:                                                                                  
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);  @ColmPrunty

Comment: oh, that should read the whole file then.

Comment: hmm, strange.... Thanks for your help @ColmPrunty    at least I can display more than i could before.

Comment: solved it! Thanks again! :)

Comment: What was it, out of curiosity.

Comment: string encrypted_text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);                                  instead of :    string encrypted_text = path;    thanks again @ColmPrunty